# Update meta.MO links

Tags: feature-request, mathoverflow, hyperlinks

This meta (and possibly the main site) had quite a lot of links to the meta.MO site, which is now replaced by a modern SE site. The previous meta was moved to http://tea.mathoverflow.net.

Is it possible somehow to edit all the links (here and on the main) to meta.MO to point to tea.MO instead?

---

Edit: Seeing how there is a new meta.MO, and new links will be flowing in soon, it might be worth getting to this issue sooner rather than later?

Comment: Is this in response to [this comment](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1618/teamathoverflownet/#Item_10)?

Comment: @Willie: More or less. It occurred to me that this is an issue when I was looking for something related to MO on this meta and found links to meta.MO which are now rotten.

Comment: `s{meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion}{tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion}/g` -- to make the proposal more concrete :). This does not mess with the  links to the new meta.MO.

Comment: @ˈjuː.zɚ79365: True, but still no reason to wait much longer...

Comment: Can we either (1) get this done already; or (2) have an explanation of why (1) is not possible?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Or (3) get an explanation why (1) must be delayed, but will be done soon.

Comment: Redirecting `meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/.*` to `tea.mathoverflow.net` is a better approach, as it fixes links on other sites too, and it's probably easier to implement.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Good idea! SE webserver logs should have some 404s from old links to meta.MO already. To better communicate the point to whoever reads the logs, I searched for "meta.MO" here and clicked on outdated links to add a few more 404s.

Answer (score 5):

Since there weren't that many links, I've gone through them manually and fixed what the searches turned up here on meta (flooding the front page, but I thought that would be less annoying than spreading the edit operation over weeks doing two a day ;).

On main, there are fewer links, those will be dealt with manually too.

Comment: What about comments?

Comment: Well, those were the larger number. SEDE returned about 50 here, and about 20 on main. It _should_ return only the ones that contain the string `meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion` in backticks from the comments here after the next data update (Sunday morning, iirc). But I may have missed one or two, or the query missed some. Anyway, I've changed the links in a lot of comments. (Also on main, now.)

Comment: Awesome. You're true to the Moderator brand that is "Fischer".

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: there are 19 questions you have edited on the front page of meta.MSE at the moment! I would have found it less annoying to have them done a few at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are proposing. As of this writing, there are just [10 posts that link to tea.mathoverflow.net](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Atea.mathoverflow.net).* There [6 on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Atea.mathoverflow.net). All but one of those are copies of [this meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12685/23504). As far as I can tell, all of these links are still active. While there has been some recent discussion of moving to the [Discourse platform](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2002/shall-we-have-tea), I haven't heard anyone propose the pages on http://tea.mathoverflow.net/ be removed.

If, by chance, those links break, we can look into fixing them.

---

* Including this question. 11 after this answer.

Comment: Links to tea.mathoverflow.net are not a problem. It's the links to `meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/` that are broken. They are found [here on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ameta.mathoverflow.net%2Fdiscussion%2F), though since there are only 22 of them, I don't know why we just didn't edit them ourselves.

Comment: @Fundamental: Ah. Now I understand. Yes, it makes a lot more sense to edit them manually if there are that few.

Comment: @Fundamental: What about the ones in the comments? (Which are the ones that cannot be edited manually by common users...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If there are any worth keeping, mod-flag to edit; otherwise obsolete.

Comment: @Fundamental: How do you propose to find these links? I propose "someone" to write a data.SE query to find them comments! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Here it is](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/268385/search-comments-by-keyword?Keyword=meta.mathoverflow.net%2Fdiscussion)... one of those comments is yours.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I posted the query in [Mods' office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19762063#19762063).

Comment: @Fundamental: And there are 19 more comments on main. Isn't it just easier to run a quick perl script `s/meta.mathoverflow.net\/discussion/tea.mathoverflow.net\/discussion` or something like that and save the trouble of flagging nearly 70 comments then have the mods edit and/or delete these comments?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Those on main can be summarily deleted.

Comment: @Fundamental: We're out of season for a summerly deletion. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It probably would be easier to run a script. (Actually it would be SQL update.) The trouble is I'd need to convince someone who has write access to the data to do it. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's summer where Pedro Tamaroff lives, so...

Comment: This thread will become incomprehensible after/if the script is run.

Comment: @JonEricson Since there aren't so many links, it's doable by hand, I've already started updating the links. If one had a redirect `meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/xyz -> tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/xyz`, that would also fix links from elsewhere, and that could be useful. But letting everybody fix their own works too.